# GraphQL query is returning undefined variables from complex query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I am new to graphQL and I am having a few problems querying my database.

When I execute a complex query, the data at higher levels is available but the data at lower levels is read as undefined. However, when I console.log() the data, I can see it in the console (but sometimes I have to wait for a couple of seconds before I can see it).

I think this may be because the process of fetching the data is taking a while, and when I try to read the data not all of it has been fetched.

I have also noticed some unusual behaviour. The page I am rendering has one large and complex query in the parent component, and one smaller and simpler query in a child component. If I comment out the code such that the smaller query is not executed, the query in the parent component works fine and all data is fetched. However, if both queries are executed, the smaller query in the child component works, but the query in the parent component fails to fetch deeply nested data.

Is it likely that the two separate queries interfere with each other when rendering information on the same page?

Any advice or solutions would be very helpful!

The query is:

```js
const ALL_USERS_QUERY = gql`
    query ALL_USERS_QUERY {
      users {
        id
        friends {
          user {
              id
          }
          id
          currentAmount
          totalAmount
          type
          country {
            id
            city {
              address {
                name
              }
              position
            }
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```

Comment: You could be right;  1.) If the server has a timeout on the time it takes to resolve data, it could be terminating the requests for the deeper nested information and just returning what it can.  It is hard to determine if this is the case unless we see what your server config looks like.  2.) The resolvers are not correctly implemented and/or is not returning the correct data.  Do you have access to the GraphQL server to look at the implemenation of the resolver functions?

Comment: My resolver looks like: const Query = { users: forwardTo('db'), }; and doesn't have any more specific detail. Should i change this? I think it may be the former issue  though since sometimes the data is resolved and sometimes it is not. Is there any way of getting around this?

Comment: Can you query the individual fields in a separate call and see if you consistently receive data?

Comment: `const Query = { users: forwardTo('db'), }; `  what does `forwardTo` function look like?  Eventually, the resolver will be making a REST call or hitting your database somehow;  What does that implementation look like?  It's very hard to determine an answer to your question without knowing what the source looks like or without a working demo. But I can (almost) guarantee there is nothing wrong with your query, if that answers your concern.

Comment: The forwardTo function delegates my query to the prisma API which should fetch all the data I am requesting.

Comment: I have noticed so unusual behaviour though. The page I am rendering has one large and complex query in the parent component, and one smaller and simpler query in a child component. If I comment out the code such that the smaller query is not executed, the query in the parent component works fine and all data is fetched. However, if both queries are executed, the smaller query in the child component works, but the query in the parent component fails to fetch deeply nested data. Is it likely that the two separate queries interfere with each other when rendering information on the same page?

Comment: Ohh, i see.  I hadn't noticed you were building your server with Prisma;  Can you provide an example of which part(s) of your query works and how many data points are returned?

Comment: Also, if you run both your complex query multiple times, is it consistently returning the same `null` values?

Comment: Lastly, how many `users` do you have in your db?

Comment: All parts of my query work consistently until three levels deep, so city returns undefined and anything beyond it is inaccessible. There are about 50 users in my db.

Comment: I tried to break up the query into separate calls but this made the problem worse as when I commented out the query in the child component, the query in the parent component also did not work (beyond three levels deep). Whereas before breaking it up the query into separate calls, it would have.

Comment: Interesting... When you break the query up into separate calls, how many rows are being returned in total?

Comment: It is always city (and any data nested deeper than city) which returns undefined, so when i break it up into seperate calls all other rows but city and beyond are returned fine. Sometimes, users returns undefined but if this happens I usually just refresh the page and this problem goes away.

Comment: Any chance your big query is returning more than 1000 nodes?